# Insert into two tables simultaneously, using **ID**(primary key, auto increment) from first table to store data on second table

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.2

I need to store data on two tables simultaneously.
with first table **window** having columns (ID, start_time, stop_time, message) and second table **windowClients** having columns (ID, Clients).

ID is auto-incremented in table **window**, i want to insert 'Clients' into **windowClients** with that same ID.

**window**

| ID | start_time | stop_time | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-12-03 15:13:00 | 2022-10-03 15:13:00 | hello |
| 101 | 2022-10-15 13:10:00 | 2022-10-03 15:13:00 | test |

**windowClients**

| ID | Clients |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 443 |
| 100 | 147 |
| 100 | 600 |
| 101 | 556 |
| 101 | 555 |

How should i insert the following data in both of two tables at the same time:

```
start_time : 2022-12-25 11:11:00 
stop_time  : 2022-10-26 11:11:00 
message    : Holiday timeout
Clients    : 256, 727, 600, 535
```

i can do the following but it's probably not a good way.

`Insert into window (columns) values (value)`

`Insert into windowClients (ID, Clients)  values ((select max(ID) from window), (443))`

Comment: Is there any problem to do inserts in one transaction?

Comment: But how do i fetch ID from `Window` table to insert in a record in `windowClients` table.